# OpenGL Drawing Axis in Corner

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I've been searching on how to draw an Indicator-Axis in my OpenGL scene. The project's nested in a Qt OpenGL widget, but I think the problem is independent of Qt.

I have found on here and forums from years ago that suggest storing the viewport and data, loading new ones for the botttom corner, apply my rotations and draw, then restore the matrices. This seems the most beneficial to me, but I'm guessing I'm still missing some critical info in my OpenGL knowledge.

For now I just have it drawing a red line from -x to x, so I expected to have a red square in the bottom left of the screen:

```
void GLWidget::drawAxis()
{
    float tempPro[16];
    float tempMod[16];
    glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, &tempPro[0]);
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, &tempMod[0]);

    glViewport(0, 0, 50, 50);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45.0f, 1.0f, 0.1f, 20.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glPushMatrix();
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glEnable( GL_LINE_SMOOTH );
        glLineWidth( 1.5 );
        glVertex3f(-1000, 0, 0);
        glVertex3f(1000, 0, 0);
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();

    glViewport(0, 0, 960, 600);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadMatrixf(tempPro);
    gluPerspective(45.0f, (960.0/600.0), 0.1f, 400.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadMatrixf(tempMod);
}
```

Instead I get nothing, just a large empty scene, and I'm unsure how to proceed. My paintGL is essentially:

```
void GLWidget::paintGL()
{    
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    Camera.Render();

    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(50.0f, 0.0f, 50.0f);
        glVertex3f(50.0f, 0.0f, -50.0f);
        glVertex3f(-50.0f, 0.0f, -50.0f);
        glVertex3f(-50.0f, 0.0f, 50.0f);
    glEnd();

    drawAxis();
```

}

Not calling the draw-axis function still gives me my plane, with it, I get a large blank scene. Am I missing something in how I'm implementing the drawAxis? Should I setup another camera for the function or something like that?

Comment: Try adding a call to `glDisable` with `GL_DEPTH_TEST` before drawing the lines.

Comment: Well removing the viewport section from the function I get a red line across my regular scene, so I'm unsure that'd help. 
Still tried it though, to no avail.

Comment: when you say section, you mean from `glViewport` to `glBegin`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can use glPushMatrix() and glPopMatrix() to save and restore the state of your Projection and ModelView matrices.
- Your not setting up your ModelView matrix to anything useful.

Try something like this:

```
void GLWidget::drawAxis()
{
    glViewport(0, 0, 50, 50);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPushMatrix();
    gluPerspective(45.0f, 1.0f, 0.1f, 20.0f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();
    //This really has to come from your camera....
    gluLookAt(10.0f,10.0f,10.0f, 0.0f,0.0f,0.0f, 0.0f,0.1f,0.0f);

    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glEnable( GL_LINE_SMOOTH );
    glLineWidth( 1.5 );
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex3f(-1000, 0, 0);
        glVertex3f(1000, 0, 0);
    glEnd();

    //Restore View
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPopMatrix();
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPopMatrix();
    glViewport(0, 0, 960, 600);
}
```

Comment: I thought Push/Pop was considered depricated or just bad to use today (so said another post on here). But I gave your suggestion a try, it resulted in the same blank screen.
I thought maybe it was because I was in Qt, so I loaded up the original C++/freeglut that ran on the glutMianLoop and still the same issue for my original code and your suggestion. I'm unsure what I'm missing.

Comment: Is is depreciated with OpenGL 3.1, but so is glMatrixMode(), glColor3f(), glTranslatef(), glBegin() and glEnd(). So if you are still using the fixed function pipeline, you might as well use Push/Pop :-). I would reduce the drawAxis method down to just the Begin/End of the line drawing. You should see your plane and a line. If that works, add just the Viewports back. You should see the plane and the line in the bottom left hand corner. Then you'll have to work on your projection and modelView matrix again...

Comment: Wow, I really need to learn modern OpenGL. I got it working with w bit of the guidance you presented and the 2-D overlay from another questions on stack (I kept looking for 3D). So I have the corner axis showing but now it's messing up my ray-selection as I pop matrices. I'll keep working on it, thanks for the help.